# "Illegal start of expression" in "private"

Tags: java, private

I'd like to know how I could fix the `illegal start of expression` error on line 3

```
1 public class Example {
2     public static void main(String[] args) {
3         private int n;
4     }
5 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will get a better response if you indent / use braces in a more standard way for Java.

Comment: better late than never!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declarations with scope (i.e. `private`, `protected`, or `public`) must be *outside* your functions, including the `main()` one. Move these declarations to the class level to fix this syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The `private` is being used in the body of a method.  It can not be used there.  It can be used in the body of a class ... outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

`private`, `protected`, or `public` are ***access modifiers***. They should be used with  member variables or methods of a `Class`.

```
Class MyClass{
  // private can be used here
  private JFrame window;


  public static void main(String[] args){
     //private can not be used here. It makes no sense
     JFrame localWindow;


  }

}
```